# How to you get verbose output from ld when using Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How do you get the ld linker to be verbose when you use Cargo? I've tried [several things](https://github.com/ctaggart/octh_examples/blob/e7848fa4a417ab5bfd8baae40c8f25f36d2e8c92/.cargo/config#L7-L24) in `.cargo/config`, but without luck. What would the right settings be? When using gcc directly, I can just do `-Wl,--verbose`.

```
[build]
rustflags = [
    "-C", "prefer-dynamic",
    # "-Z", "pre-link-arg=-pthread",
    "-C", "link-arg=-pthread",
    "-C", "link-arg=-fopenmp",
    # "-C", "link-arg=-LC:/Octave/Octave-4.2.1/lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.4",
    # "-C", "link-arg=--sysroot=C:/Octave/Octave-4.2.1",
    # "-Z", "pre-link-args=-LC:/Octave/Octave-4.2.1/lib",
    # "-Z", "pre-link-args=-LC:\\Octave\\Octave-4.2.1\\lib",
    # "-C", "link-arg=--verbose",
    # "-C", "link-arg=-v",
    # "-C", "link-arg=-Wl,--verbose",
    # "-Z", "print-link-args",
]

[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu]
linker = "C:/Octave/Octave-4.2.1/bin/gcc.exe"
# rustflags = [
#     "-C", "link-arg=-Wl,--verbose",
# ]

# [term]
# verbose = true
```

I'm [trying to build](https://github.com/ctaggart/octh/issues/18#issuecomment-306041225) a library for Octave with Rust.

Comment: `"-C", "link-arg=-Wl,--verbose"` and `"-Z", "print-link-args"` shows that `-Wl,--verbose` is being passed to my linker (`cc` on macOS 10.12). Unfortunately, my `ld` doesn't support that flag, but it is passed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the answer: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38206

```
export RUSTC_LOG=rustc_codegen_ssa::back::link=info
```